# update nested Array state reactjs

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, immutable.js, react-state

Unable to handle nested array in react state, here what I am trying I need to push value in this.state.form.contentFormArr

```
    let langulageform, contentObj,contentFormArr;   

   contentObj={heading:'',subheading:''};
    contentFormArr=[this.contentObj]

    langulageform =[
            {key:"Ar",lang:"Arabic",contentFormArr:this.contentFormArr},
            {key:"En",lang:"English",contentFormArr:this.contentFormArr},
            {key:"Ru",lang:"Russian",contentFormArr:this.contentFormArr},
            {key:"Sp",lang:"Spanish",contentFormArr:this.contentFormArr},
            {key:"Ve",lang:"Vetnamese",contentFormArr:this.contentFormArr}
        ];

    constructor(){
            super()

            this.addContentArea = this.addContentArea.bind(this)

            this.state={
                form:this.langulageform
            }

        }


    addContentArea(index){


            this.setState((state)=>{

                const contentformArr = [...state.form[index].contentFormArr,this.contentObj]

                return{
                    ...state.form.contentFormArr,
                    contentformArr
                }
            })

        }
```

I made multiple forms by the iterating this.state.form array, Now I need when the user clicks on any form box button to add more field then it will push value in particular index array and then it will iterate more fields.

Comment: please provide a running [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Well I did it but I think the way which I use is not good practice. First I made the correction on Array which I set to state as the initial value, because fore I was set array value to contentForm array when I made changes to them it set changes to everywhere on state Object.

```
langulageform =[
  {key:"Ar",lang:"Arabic",contentFormArr:[{heading:'',subheading:''}]},
  {key:"En",lang:"English",contentFormArr:[{heading:'',subheading:''}]},
  {key:"Ru",lang:"Russian",contentFormArr:[{heading:'',subheading:''}]},
           {key:"Sp",lang:"Spanish",contentFormArr:[{heading:'',subheading:''}]},
           {key:"Ve",lang:"Vetnamese",contentFormArr:[{heading:'',subheading:''}]}
    ];
```

Secondly I create one blank array and push all values in it, so that I can push value in it, This can't be done in state because of immutable object, and after getting correct index object I made corrections and return the object.

```
addContentArea(index){
this.setState((state)=>{

  let Arr=[];

  state.form.map((e,i)=>{
     Arr.push(e);

     if(i===index){
        Arr.contentFormArr.push({})
     }

  })



  return{
     Arr
   }
})
}
```

I did it because I feel to deal with multidimensional immutable arrays are bit tricky this is not an optimized way but it works every time and I have checked that the react component lifecycle methods are also working fine with this.

Comment: if some child component consumes `this.state.form.En.contentFromArr` as a prop and is/becomes `PureComponent` or type of(custom `shouldComponentUpdate`) then it will not be updated after value mutated with `push`.

Comment: @skyboyer but it showing me updated values and it's working well as I was expected, but it made me confuse what I feel if you set some value into react state then it will become immutable and if there will be child array that will not be immutable. well, I don't know but it's working well.

Comment: do you use `PureComponent` or custom `shouldComponentUpdate` in child component? I guess you don't by now. If you leave this code with `push` then some day maybe other developer will introduce `shouldComponentUpdate` for optimization purpose and will realize that component is not updating.

Comment: @skyboyer Ya I am not using pure component for now actually I am new for react, I am not aware of these tricks techniques in React, Well, what you suggest for it?? according to best practice